# Get recent activity (comments, shares, likes) for user in Facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-timeline

Suppose I want to get 20 last likes on my all posts. What FQL query should I run?

I've tried this query, but it provides wrong ordering (it orders by `post` date, not `like` date):

```
SELECT object_id FROM like WHERE post_id IN (
    SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id = me()
) LIMIT 20
```

I need to get some kind of 'Twitter timeline' functionality. Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 2):

According to this [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like), Facebook API FQL does not support how to get time of any like via **like table**.